# react native Android gmail and firebase phone otp login not working in apk release

Tags: reactjs

...
react native login not working in apk release but working in debug ,
i try it many time doing sha-1 key adding to fire base but it not working
...

```
try {
 await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices();
 const {accessToken, idToken} = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
 setloggedIn(true);
} catch (error) {
 if (error.code === statusCodes.SIGN_IN_CANCELLED) {
   // user cancelled the login flow
   alert('Cancel');
 } else if (error.code === statusCodes.IN_PROGRESS) {
   alert('Signin in progress');
   // operation (f.e. sign in) is in progress already
 } else if (error.code === statusCodes.PLAY_SERVICES_NOT_AVAILABLE) {
   alert('PLAY_SERVICES_NOT_AVAILABLE');
   // play services not available or outdated
 } else {
   // some other error happened
 }
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added the statusCodes.SIGN_IN_CANCELLED, statusCodes.IN_PROGRESS, and statusCodes.PLAY_SERVICES_NOT_AVAILABLE checks. These are just some of the possible errors that could occur, so you may want to add more.

```
try {
 await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices();
 const {accessToken, idToken} = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
 setloggedIn(true);
} catch (error) {
 if (error.code === statusCodes.SIGN_IN_CANCELLED) {
   // user cancelled the login flow
   alert('Cancel');
 } else if (error.code === statusCodes.IN_PROGRESS) {
   alert('Signin in progress');
   // operation (f.e. sign in) is in progress already
 } else if (error.code === statusCodes.PLAY_SERVICES_NOT_AVAILABLE) {
   alert('PLAY_SERVICES_NOT_AVAILABLE');
   // play services not available or outdated
 } else {
   // some other error happened
 }
}
};
```